$ \lambda^{*}(n) $ minimal polynomials
I already asked a closely related question on MO, but didn't received any answer.
Considering the modular lambda function, the values of $ \lambda^{*}(n) $ for some integers are given on here.
Is there a way to calculate the coefficients of the minimal polynomials of each $ \lambda^{*}(n) $ ?
Here you have the minimal polynomials for the first $10$ positive integers
\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
 n  &  P_n(x) \\ \hline
 1 & 2x^2-1        \\ \hline
 2 & x^2+2x-1    \\ \hline
 3 & 16x^4-16x^2+1 \\ \hline
 4 & x^2-6x+1  \\ \hline
5 & 16x^{8} - 32x^{6} + 88x^4 - 72 x^2 + 1 \\ \hline
6 & x^{4} + 12x^{3} +2x^2 - 12x +1 \\ \hline
7 & 256x^4 - 256x^2 + 1 \\ \hline
8 & x^{4} - 20x^{3} - 26x^2 - 20x +1 \\ \hline
9 & 16x^{8} - 32x^{6} + 792x^4 - 776x^2 + 1 \\ \hline
10 & x^{4} + 36x^{3} + 2x^2 - 36 x + 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Mathematica code is given in https://oeis.org/A084540

@MaxAlekseyev yes I know, I used that code to find the polynomials, but I wonder if it's possible to compute the coefficients analytically
